Will 2.1" schwalbe MTB tire in 25mm rim become wider that 2.25" in 19mm rim?
will be the 29" Schwalbe Racing Ralph tyre of width 2.10 in the rim of internal width 25mm wider than 2.25 wide RR in 19mm wide rim?
I am looking for replacement of my broken rim and I see that the 25mm wide rims are now basically standard but I would like to be able to still fit R. Ralphs in to my frame

Assuming that the manufacturer's claims about the tyre width are accurate (which they absolutely are not), a 6mm increase in rim width will not make a 2.10" (53,34mm) tyre wider than a 2.25" (57,15mm) one.
The rim width increase transfers into the circumference of the tyre, not the diameter, so a 6mm increase in rim width only causes about a 2mm increase in tyre width. But if you are playing with a ~5mm tolerance in your frame, you cannot rely on the tyre width markings and just have to try it out. Because the tyre width markings cannot be trusted when it comes down to the millimeters.

I ended trying it. Here is the result:



Nominal tire width
Rim internal width
Resulting width




2.25"  (57mm)
19mm
55mm


2.10" (53mm)
25mm
52mm




Hey, did you generate this with an on-line service? It would seem useful, can you provide a link?

Unfortunately no. I asked schwalbe but no response so I just bought a rim and tested it. I created this question just to share my result. Thank You for hint with circumference.
